# Select box appears as 2 when using select2 js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have included the CSS & Javascript files for select2 JS included with the "OREO ADMIN TEMPLATE" (Google it). I am getting 2 select boxes. The top one is the select2 js selectbox which works like it should and the bottom is regular multiple select that comes with the OREO admin template. It's like its duplicating. And I am not sure why or how.

[image]

Select box code in form:

```
<select class="form-control show-tick ms select2" id="countries" name="countries[]" multiple data-placeholder="Select GEO Target">
    @foreach($countries as $c)
        <option value="{{ $c->id }}">{{ $c->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And I also included CSS at the top of the page:

```
<!-- Select2 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/select2/select2.css" />
```

And Javascript at the bottom. Yes, the jQuery 3.7.1 file is there.

```
<script src="/assets/plugins/select2/select2.min.js"></script> <!-- Select2 Js -->
```

I have checked and all files are in the correct location in the picture included you can see the styles are working.

I used this code to fire the select2:

```
<script>
    $(".select2").select2();
</script>
```

When i tried putting it in this format:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".select2").select2(); 
    });
```

It caused issues so I left it without the document-ready function.

Any clues?

Comment: Hi, change this `$(".select2").select2();` to `$("#countries").select2();`.

Comment: I as well tried that.

Comment: I removed "form-control" form the class of the <select> and that seems to have fixed the duplicated box. Now to figure out how to get it to look the way i want.

Comment: I also switched to the bootstrap multi select option Oreo offers in their template demo and it duplicates as well

Comment: `"It caused issues"` - what issues? Does the console show errors?